# Cannot run import in saved jupyter notebook on code-server - but it works if the file i new

Tags: jupyter-notebook, code-server

I use a virtual machine in Azure. It runs Ubuntu 20.04 and docker. I run two docker containers, one with code-server and one with SWAG (nginx reverse proxy). I can log on to code-server and run code. I try to follow the code in this notebook https://rockpool.ai/basics/hello_MNIST.html. When I create new Jupyter notebook (and dont save it yet), it runs fine. If I save it, I can run up until this statement ‘from rockpool.nn.modules import LIF’ (cell named 11), and then it fails with this error:  ‘Cannot execute code, session has been disposed. Please try restarting the Kernel.’

I can create a new Jupyter notebook, copy the code over, and it runs fine… until I save it, and the same problem occurs. I have tried saving it a folder in the docker container and with 777 permissions, and also to a folder that is mapped to the host machine and with 777 permissions.

Comment: Take this complex code out of the equation. If you make a new `.ipynb` put in a single cell of `print('Hello World')`, run it, and save it does that work?

Comment: Hi Wayne, thank you for the tip. Yes, it works fine when only doing print(‘Hello World’). It also works well if I create a new Notebook, copy the code from the saved notebook that fails, paste it into the new notebook and run. However, if I click save on the new notebook and run, then it fails.